# How CAS handle session timeout

Tags: session-timeout, cas

My understanding about CAS:

Have 1 CAS server and 2 CAS client,

client1 login success through CAS
user works on client1, so client1's session is refreshed by user action. But CAS server session timeout.
user try access client2, when check CAS found the session is timeout, so need login again, but the client1 is already login.

It does not make sense, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: client2 is a different user with a different session timeout?  Or are you saying that client1's session times out when client2 logs in?

Comment: client1 and client2 are all j2ee web application.

1.user go to client1's site
2.redirect to CAS server, login successful
3.user click links on client1's site, so client1's own session is refreshed, but CAS has time out
4,user go to client2's site, client2 redirect to CAS server, now must login again.


this is my understanding, and I think when in the step 4, user donot need to login again

Answer (score 4):

CAS uses "services" to differentiate the websites.  Within cas there would be a "client1" service and a "client2" service, each with their own TicketGrantingTicket.  The session timeout is controlled through the CAS servers ticket expiration policy for TGT's described here:

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Ticket+Expiration+Policy

In this way, each of the servers would have their own timeout.  So when I go to client1 and click a link, this would have no effect on the session timeout for client2.

If you wanted the two websites to affect their timeouts, you'll need to make them use the same service and investigate the use of Proxy Granting tickets:

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough

Comment: Is there any other SSO solution that support such case?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Client1 might still be logged in is because you are not handling the logout post that CAS sends out when it expires a user's TicketGrantingTicket.

When a logout event happens in CAS it sends a logout post to all it's registered services.  Client1 needs to handle this by looking at the request.  If by chance you are using PHP you need to take a look at $_REQUEST for a logout message.